# How to compare lists in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

***Input***

```
one<-c("Rainy and sunny;thundering;lightning","dismal and dreary;thundering")
two<-c("Overcast;lightning","Overcast;dismal and dreary")
df2<-data.frame(one,two)
```

I want to compare the strings in the lists by row and extract what is the same, and what is different in new columns

***The output I am expecting is:***

```
same<-c("lightning","dismal and dreary")
different_Incol1ButNot2<-c("Rainy and sunny;thundering","thundering")
different_Incol2ButNot1<-c("Overcast","Overcast")

df2<-data.frame(one,two,same,different_Incol1ButNot2,different_Incol2ButNot1,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

***which should output:***

```
    one                                  two                        same               different_Incol1ButNot2  different_Incol2ButNot1
 Rainy and sunny;thundering;lightning   Overcast;lightning          lightning          Rainy and sunny;thundering      Overcast
 dismal and dreary;thundering           Overcast;dismal and dreary  dismal and dreary  thundering                      Overcast
```

***so my first thought was to split and list each string:***

```
df3$one<-as.list(strsplit(df3$one, ";"))
df3$two<-as.list(strsplit(df3$two, ";"))
```

However now I do not know how to compare row-wise the lists I have created within the dataframe so I guess the question is how do I make these row wise comparisons between lists of strings within a dataframe or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: your dataframe contains factor columns based on your code, not lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(strsplit(as.character(.), ';'))) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(same = toString(intersect(one, two)), 
        differs_1 = toString(setdiff(one, two)), 
        differs_2 = setdiff(two, one))
```

which gives,

> ```
> Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
> Groups: <by row>
>
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>         one       two              same                   differs_1 differs_2
>      <list>    <list>             <chr>                       <chr>     <chr>
> 1 <chr [3]> <chr [2]>         lightning Rainy and sunny, thundering  Overcast
> 2 <chr [2]> <chr [2]> dismal and dreary                  thundering  Overcast
> ```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should use `character`columns, not factor (by default `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`), ie:

```
one <- c("Rainy and sunny;thundering;lightning","dismal and dreary;thundering")
two <- c("Overcast;lightning","Overcast;dismal and dreary")
df2 <- data.frame(one,two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can use set operations, namely `intersect` and `setdiff` here. You can try them outside but a function is handy.

```
compare_strings <- function(x){
  l <- sapply(x, strsplit, ";")
  list(one=x$one,
       two=x$two,
       same=intersect(l[[1]], l[[2]]),
       different_Incol1ButNot2=paste(setdiff(l[[1]], l[[2]]), collapse=";"),
       different_Incol2ButNot1=paste(setdiff(l[[2]], l[[1]]), collapse=";")                                 
  )
}
```

Applied on a single line of your `df2`, it returns a named list with all the components you want.

```
> compare_strings(df2[1, ])
$one
[1] "Rainy and sunny;thundering;lightning"

$two
[1] "Overcast;lightning"

$same
[1] "lightning"

$different_Incol1ButNot2
[1] "Rainy and sunny;thundering"

$different_Incol2ButNot1
[1] "Overcast"
```

If we apply this to every row of your `data.frame`, and `rbind` the resulting list of lists then we have the final `data.frame` you want:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(i) compare_strings(df2[i, ])))
one                                    two                         
[1,] "Rainy and sunny;thundering;lightning" "Overcast;lightning"        
[2,] "dismal and dreary;thundering"         "Overcast;dismal and dreary"
same                different_Incol1ButNot2      different_Incol2ButNot1
[1,] "lightning"         "Rainy and sunny;thundering" "Overcast"             
[2,] "dismal and dreary" "thundering"                 "Overcast"
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Alas points awarded to the dplyr answer because of its neatness

Comment: I knew there would be a dplyr answer ;-)